# jQuery plugin only runs once

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I am working on a custom plugin to use on a web-page of mine. This plugin is used to paginate, sort, search and enable selection on a html table. I've got the basics of it done, most of it just needs to be reformatted for speed, however..

But my problem is that after I change the page, I can't interact with the table.

My code to interact with the table is :

```
$.fn.tableManipulation = function( objOptions ) {
    return this.each( function() {
        var tm = new $.tableManipulation( objOptions ) ;

        // page controls
        $( "td#btnNext" ).click( function( event ) {
            objOptions = tm.changePage( "next" ) ;
        } ) ;
        $( "td#btnPrev" ).click( function( event ) {
            objOptions = tm.changePage( "previous" ) ;
        } ) ;

        // search controls
        $( "button#searchSubmit" ).click( function( event ) {
            tm.searchTable() ;
        } ) ;

        // sort controls
        $( "TD[id*='sortColumn']" ).click( function( event ) {
            tm.sortColumns( parseInt( this.id.match( /\d+/g ), 10 ) ) ;
        } ) ;

        // sort selection
        $( "TR[id*='row']" ).click( function( event ) {
            tm.setSelection( $(this) ) ;
        } ) ;
    } ) ;
} ;
```

Thanks

Comment: Just my opinion, but you would be better off with a 3rd-party control deigned to do this sort of thing (good learning exercise though).

Comment: Yes, I was recently experimenting this with DataTables and JQWidgets. I want to learn more about Javascript and jQuery though as my knowledge is fairly limited currently

Comment: +1 for supplying a JSFiddle... and for trying something this complicated to learn JQuery :) I highly recommend you also learn TypeScript or one of the other higher-level Javascript pseudo-languages as they will let you write far more complicated code with less error (and generally neater) and they just output Javascript.

Comment: I'll have a look at them, I normally use languages like C# or PHP so JavaScript and all it's plugins are just confusing to me. I'll have a look at them though, I intend to be doing a lot of research into JS so the more the merrier! Thanks :)

Comment: I prefer C# myself, but TypeScript has let me cope with the vagaries of the *very* loosely-typed Javascript.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll have a look now then. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the deferred version of `on` (applied to document, with a selector) instead of `click` so that the events do not get detached:

```
// page controls
$(document).on("click", "td#btnNext", function( event ) {
    alert("next");
    objOptions = tm.changePage( "next" ) ;
} ) ;
```

The cause of the problem is that you are recreating the elements that events were attached to, but not always reconnecting the events to the new elements (the old ones no longer exist). If the names/ids will not change then it is easier to listen for those events at a higher level (e.g. `document`, but it can be any element up the hierarchy that does not change).

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you very much. Oh okay, I didn't know that's why it was happening. I assumed that keeping ID's the same would have let the code know that I wanted the same thing to happen for each occurrence of it. I'll have to take a look at more information on this then, I think!

Comment: Keeping the same id does not work. You are connecting an event to a *specific instance of the element, based on a search/filter*. Only the deferred options do the search for the element *at event time*.